# Combo box to filter another combo box

Tags: sql, ms-access, combobox

I have a table consisting of three columns; the first is an **ID**, the second describes the **activity** assigned to that ID and the third defines the **category** that the activity falls into. I have a combo box, which contains a list of all of the categories lifted from another table. I would like to have a second combo box, which, on selection of a specific category, allows the user to pick an activity from that category.

My knowledge of access and databases is quite limited, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What code have you tried

Comment: I have sorted this problem now, I have done a bit of reading up

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly complex thing to actually do, but it is doable. If you're dead set on it, it will require  learning a bit of both VBA and SQL. You essentially need to write VBA code that will first define SQL queries as a string based on your choice in the comboboxes and then passes that string as the source of each following combobox.

If your experience with access and databases is limited as you say it is, you may want to opt for a simpler solution for the time being. If you want to see more in detail how something like this would work check out http://www.fontstuff.com/access/acctut15.htm

Answer (score 0):

There is a walkthrough [here at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb404901%28v=office.12%29.aspx) on synchronizing two comboboxes. It is a common feature so internet searching will locate other similar examples.